# Java - Negate a polynomial

Tags: java, junit, polynomial-math, negate

I am trying to negate a polynomial expression so that the following tests are correct with my polynomial expressions being defined as `Term(coefficient, exponent)`. So my `public Term negate() throws Overflow` method passes these tests.

```
Term(min,2) -> expected = Overflow
Term(-7,2) -> expected = (7,2)
Term(0,2) -> expected = (0,2)
Term(7,2) -> expected = (-7,2)
Term(max,2) -> expected = (-max,2)
```

EDIT: I have the following method within Term:

```
public Term negate() throws Overflow {

}
```

and the following in the Term constructor:

```
public Term(int c, int e) throws NegativeExponent{
    if (e < 0) throw new NegativeExponent();
    coef = c;
    expo = (c == 0 && e != 0) ? 0 : e;
}
```

The tests above are in a seperate JUnit file, but I am trying to make the `negate()` method pass the tests.

Comment: I don't see a question here ...

Comment: What is min and max here? Any limit that you specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only answer this because I answered [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408797/java-junit-comparing-two-polynomial-objects/13408841#13408841)... so you might want to clarify a little more in your post.

Perhaps you want

```
public Term negate() throws Overflow, NegativeExponent {
    if (coef == min)
        throw new Overflow();
    return new Term(-coef, expo);
}
```

You might want to consider renaming `Overflow` to something more specific as well (so as to fully distinguish it from a `StackOverflowError`).

Comment: +1 for constructive criticism. I remember this `Term` from yesterday.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded question. I wrote something similar to this code too, but eclipse told me I should also throw `NegativeExponent`, I didn't think I would need to as the tests only every want me to throw `Overflow`.

Comment: @user1828314 It's impossible for me to know what the problem is without seeing more of the code.

Comment: @user1828314 See my edit. You need to take `NegativeExponent` into account because you throw it in the constructor of `Term`.